# Why is there a MAUI "Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS Unhandled Managed Exception" when Narrating on iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, maui

> It appears that when attempting to call

```
mauiCognitiveServices.Narrate
```

before a narration cancelation is completed may cause an exception. It is not a consistent error, but reoccurs frequently, apparently if the timing between calls is short.

An example of the stack trace being received is:

```
Thread finished:  #42
    0x1010500b4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D5D874DC-AC3D-4CC9-BECE-38945AFA76E1/Sentry.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : _ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode
    0x10103b1b0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D5D874DC-AC3D-4CC9-BECE-38945AFA76E1/Sentry.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : _ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode
    0x10108e180 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D5D874DC-AC3D-4CC9-BECE-38945AFA76E1/Sentry.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : _ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode
    0x10104f8c8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D5D874DC-AC3D-4CC9-BECE-38945AFA76E1/Sentry.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : _ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode

2023-07-18 22:14:14.330 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[3593:17702805] 
Unhandled Exception:
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeoutAsync(TaskNode asyncWaiter, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Media.TextToSpeechImplementation.SpeakAsync(String text, SpeechOptions options, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Sentry.MauiCognitiveServices.Narrate(String statement) in C:\Projects\Sentry\Sentry\Control\MauiCognitiveServices.cs:line 100
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.DispatchItemWithAutoreleasePool(Object workItem, Thread currentThread)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
  
.._..._..)......
0x1d783a558  03 01 00 54 7f 23 03 d5 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91  ...T.#...{
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================

{...._.
0x1d783a578  c0 03 5f d6 7f 23 03 d5 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91  .._..#...{..
....

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
=================================================================

2023-07-18 22:14:14.332 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[3593:17702805] Unhandled managed exception: The operation was canceled. (System.OperationCanceledException)
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeoutAsync(TaskNode asyncWaiter, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Media.TextToSpeechImplementation.SpeakAsync(String text, SpeechOptions options, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Sentry.MauiCognitiveServices.Narrate(String statement) in C:\Projects\Sentry\Sentry\Control\MauiCognitiveServices.cs:line 100
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallbackDefaultContext.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.DispatchItemWithAutoreleasePool(Object workItem, Thread currentThread)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispa
    0x1f85df214 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1f867b118 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : pthread_kill
    0x19fe1f178 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib : abort
    0x100d5d868 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D5D874DC-AC3D-4CC9-BECE-38945AFA76E1/Sentry.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type
    0x100f337c8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D5D874DC-AC3D-4CC9-BECE-38945AFA76E1/Sentry.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : _ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode
    0x100f85f64 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D5D874DC-AC3D-4CC9-BECE-38945AFA76E1/Sentry.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : _ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode

 at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()

d2 01 10 00 d4  
    0x100f85cb0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D5D874DC-AC3D-4CC9-BECE-38945AFA76E1/Sentry.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : _ZNK3icu6number23NumberFormatterSettingsINS0_24LocalizedNumberFormatterEE10toSkeletonER10UErrorCode
    0x1f86756b8 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : _pthread_start
    0x1f8674b88 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : thread_start

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1d783a558):0x1d783a548  ff 0f 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6 10 29 80 
......
0x1d783a568  07 ed ff 97 bf 03 00 91 fd 7b c1 a8 ff 0f 5f d6  .........
tch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
```

at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()

Manually slowing the push of the buttons generating the narration call seems to prevent the exception.